# Create Scheduled Task download ClamAV daily using Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, scheduled-tasks

So I'm looking to download the ClamAV cvd definition files on a server so that I can keep my clients updated regularly.

In order to keep it separate from any login/admin account, I'd like to use a service account.

This is the powershell script that I have so far;

```sh
Start Microsoft-Edge:http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
sleep 120
Get-Process -Name "*Edge*" | Stop-Process
Start Microsoft-Edge:http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
sleep 120
Get-Process -Name "*Edge*" | Stop-Process
Get-Item -Path "C:\Temp\*.cvd" | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Updates\ClamAV\*.cvd"
```

Comment: What part of your script isn't working for you? You can usually use powershell to download files with something like `Invoke-WebRequest -uri 'http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd' -OutFile "$env:TEMP\daily.cvd"` if ms-edge is giving you trouble

Comment: The problem is you have with ClamAV website is that its protected with Cloudflare and thats why Im having to use Edge

Answer (score 0):

This powershell script works for me, and should run fine as a scheduled task under a different service account:

```sh
# Download both files using edge to bypass cloudflare
Start-Process msedge http://database.clamav.net/main.cvd
Start-Process msedge http://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
sleep -Seconds 30
# close edge
Get-Process msedge | Stop-Process
# move files from default edge location to updates folder
Get-Item "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\*.cvd" | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Updates\ClamAV\*.cvd"
```

Alternatively, you can skip the move step by specifying a different download folder in edge. Run edge as your service account user > Settings > Downloads > Location > set the folder path you want